# azure powershell prompting login after logging in

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to use a template to deploy an ASE. I can't use the UI since they made it clear that you can't deploy to a pre-existing subnet in the portal, but you can by using a PS template. 
I run the script and it prompts New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
But I've logged in.
After researching I've tried
1. Uninstalling AzureRM and re-installing
2. Running update-module and updating

[image]

Comment: Please check the version of Azure PowerShell with this script `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`,

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your the error message is:

```
Login-AzureRMAccount  is available with different modules.
```

For eg if you are using azureRM module cmdlets you should probably login with:

```
AzureRM.profile\Login-AzureRmAccount
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you select the right subscription?
We can use this PowerShell command to select subscription `Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName`.

Also, we should check the version of your Azure PowerShell with this command `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`, the latest version is 3.9.0. Please try other commands to make sure the Azure PowerShell works fine.